# Error pulling my image from docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerhub

I’ve created a docker image and pushed it to docker hub as public repo.
When I try to do pull it, I get an error:

```
docker pull myname/book-store

Error response from daemon: manifest for myname/book-store:latest not found
```

I see this image in the docker hub

I’ve pushed it to docker hub:

```
docker tag book-store:1.0.1 myuser/book-store:1.0.0
docker push myuser/book-store:1.0.0
```

Any idea what could be missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying a tag when pulling your image, so docker tries to pull `:latest`, which isn't there.

```
docker pull myname/book-store:1.0.0
```

Should work OK

There's a good post about `:latest` [here](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375)